# can't connect to DB with node.js on server.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, server, openshift

I'm newby to `Node.js` and back-end development. I'm trying to create web api for my mobile app on `OPENSHIFT` server. But I'm living problems. I'm trying to connect to DB on `server.js` in order to set the routings(http requests) I need. Whereas, somehow I can't define my DB in `server.js`. I can connect in any other file, I tried, but when I try to connect `through`server.js` I get error - whole app crashes on server. I'll try to explain with code examples.

Here is my `server.js`

```
#!/bin/env node
//  OpenShift sample Node application
var express = require('express');
var fs      = require('fs');
var db = require("./db_connection");//when I delete this line, there is not any error.

/**
 *  Define the sample application.
 */
var SampleApp = function() {

    //  Scope.
    var self = this;


    /*  ================================================================  */
    /*  Helper functions.                                                 */
    /*  ================================================================  */

    /**
     *  Set up server IP address and port # using env variables/defaults.
     */
    self.setupVariables = function() {
        //  Set the environment variables we need.
        self.ipaddress = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP;
        self.port      = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;

        if (typeof self.ipaddress === "undefined") {
            //  Log errors on OpenShift but continue w/ 127.0.0.1 - this
            //  allows us to run/test the app locally.
            console.warn('No OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP var, using 127.0.0.1');
            self.ipaddress = "127.0.0.1";
        };
    };


    /**
     *  Populate the cache.
     */
    self.populateCache = function() {
        if (typeof self.zcache === "undefined") {
            self.zcache = { 'index.html': '' };
        }

        //  Local cache for static content.
        self.zcache['index.html'] = fs.readFileSync('./index.html');
    };


    /**
     *  Retrieve entry (content) from cache.
     *  @param {string} key  Key identifying content to retrieve from cache.
     */
    self.cache_get = function(key) { return self.zcache[key]; };


    /**
     *  terminator === the termination handler
     *  Terminate server on receipt of the specified signal.
     *  @param {string} sig  Signal to terminate on.
     */
    self.terminator = function(sig){
        if (typeof sig === "string") {
           console.log('%s: Received %s - terminating sample app ...',
                       Date(Date.now()), sig);
           process.exit(1);
        }
        console.log('%s: Node server stopped.', Date(Date.now()) );
    };


    /**
     *  Setup termination handlers (for exit and a list of signals).
     */
    self.setupTerminationHandlers = function(){
        //  Process on exit and signals.
        process.on('exit', function() { self.terminator(); });

        // Removed 'SIGPIPE' from the list - bugz 852598.
        ['SIGHUP', 'SIGINT', 'SIGQUIT', 'SIGILL', 'SIGTRAP', 'SIGABRT',
         'SIGBUS', 'SIGFPE', 'SIGUSR1', 'SIGSEGV', 'SIGUSR2', 'SIGTERM'
        ].forEach(function(element, index, array) {
            process.on(element, function() { self.terminator(element); });
        });
    };


    /*  ================================================================  */
    /*  App server functions (main app logic here).                       */
    /*  ================================================================  */

    /**
     *  Create the routing table entries + handlers for the application.
     */
    self.createRoutes = function() {
        self.routes = { };

        self.routes['/asciimo'] = function(req, res) {
            var link = "http://i.imgur.com/kmbjB.png";
            res.send("<html><body><img src='" + link + "'></body></html>");
        };

        self.routes['/'] = function(req, res) {
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
            res.send(self.cache_get('index.html') );
        };

        self.routes['/All'] = function(req, res) {
            db.query("select * from users",function(err,result){
                if(err)
                    res.json(err);
                else
                    res.json(result);
            })
        };
    };


    /**
     *  Initialize the server (express) and create the routes and register
     *  the handlers.
     */
    self.initializeServer = function() {
        self.createRoutes();
        self.app = express.createServer();

        //  Add handlers for the app (from the routes).
        for (var r in self.routes) {
            self.app.get(r, self.routes[r]);
        }
    };


    /**
     *  Initializes the sample application.
     */
    self.initialize = function() {
        self.setupVariables();
        self.populateCache();
        self.setupTerminationHandlers();

        // Create the express server and routes.
        self.initializeServer();
    };


    /**
     *  Start the server (starts up the sample application).
     */
    self.start = function() {
        //  Start the app on the specific interface (and port).
        self.app.listen(self.port, self.ipaddress, function() {
            console.log('%s: Node server started on %s:%d ...',
                        Date(Date.now() ), self.ipaddress, self.port);
        });
    };

};   /*  Sample Application.  */



/**
 *  main():  Main code.
 */
var zapp = new SampleApp();
zapp.initialize();
zapp.start();
```

And here is my `db_connection.js`

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    port: "3307",
    user: "adminm*****",
    password: "zLj7Sh***",
    database: "***db"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
        console.log("COULD NOT CONNECT!!!");
    }
});

module.exports = con;
```

And here is the error I face

[image]

So, Can you help me, please? Why I can't declare any file on `server.js`?

Comment: That's not the error, that's a user-facing page. The actual error will be in your logs.

Comment: thank you for correction. So, How can I access to logs?

Comment: It depends on how you're running this app.

Comment: I tried to access logs through "rch ssh" , but I could not.

Comment: You need to find a way to get the logs. This may involve running it manually on the command-line to see STDOUT.

Comment: Use `rhc ssh <app_name>` for sshing into your app's primary gear on OpenShift Online v2, then have a look on logs in `~/app-root/logs/`. You can also `rhc tail <app>` to tail the logs. In order to connect to the database, use `OPENSHIFT_MYSQL*` [environment variables](https://developers.openshift.com/databases/mysql.html). Also note, that OpenShift Online v2 is going to be [decommissioned soon](https://blog.openshift.com/migrate-to-v3-v2-eol/).